# The tangent space of a manifold at a point given as the kernel of the jacobian of a submersion

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\phi:M\to N$ is a smooth map, $q\in N$ a regular value, and $V=\phi^{-1}(q)$. I want to show that, for each $p\in V$, $T_p(V)= \mathrm{ker}(\phi_*)\subseteq T_p(M)$ (where $\phi_*$ is the differential of $\phi$).

Since $q$ is regular, I know $\phi_*(T_p(M))=T_q(N)$. I believe I can say $\phi_*(T_p(V))=T_q(\{q\})=0$. But I don't know why $\phi_*^{-1}(0)=T_p(V)$. 
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right with the inclusion $T_p(V)\subset \ker(\phi_*)$. Just take $v\in T_p(V)$ and let $\alpha(t)$ be a curve in $V$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v$ , then we have that

$$\phi_*(v)=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\phi(\alpha(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}q=0.$$

Finally, we get the equality $T_p(V)=\ker(\phi_*)$ by dimension counting.

Comment: I know the rank of $ker(\phi_*)=m-n$ (where $m=\dim(M)$ and $n=\dim(N)$). I have a corollary than says that $\dim V=\dim(\phi^{-1}(q))=m-n$. However, the claim in my question was used to prove the theorem for said corollary. So, I don't know what to say about $\dim V$ or $\dim T_p(V)$.

Comment: We know the dimension of $V$ by the constant rank theorem for manifolds. In this case it basically tells us that we can find coordinates centered at $p\in M$ and $q\in N$ such that $\phi(x^1,\cdots,x^m)=(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$. This means that $V$ is locally defined by $\{x^{1}=\ldots=x^n=0\}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $j : V \to M$ be the canonical injection. Show that $dj(p) : T_pV \to T_pM$ induces an isomorphism between $T_pV$ and $\mathrm{ker} (d\phi(p))$.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that not only is $dj_p$ an isomorphism, it is actually the identity map, since we can write the derivative as the restriction of any smooth map that restricts to $j$, for example the identity.