# Proving that $T_pS = Ker ( df_p)$ for every p such that $p \in S$ such that $S=f^{-1}(q)$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my Assignment in smooth manifolds and I was unable to solve it.So, I am posting it here.

> If $f: M \to N$is a smooth map and  $q \in N$ is a regular value of f. Then show that $T_p S= Ker (df_p)$.

Attempt: q is a regular value means that $df_p : T_pM \to T_q N$ is surjective for all $p\in f^{-1}(q)$. Let $x\in Ker (df_p)$=> which implies that $df_p(x)=0 $ where $x\in T_pM$. To show that $x\in T_PS$ which means that x is tangent space of the set $S= f^{-1} (q)$ but  I am not able to get ideas on how should I prove that.

Conversaly, Let $x\in T_p(S)$ , then there exists an $y \in T_pM $ such that $df_p(y)=x$ by surjectivity of $df_p$, but again I am not able to make any progress.

I found a solution here:[The tangent space of a manifold at a point given as the kernel of the jacobian of a submersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532847/the-tangent-space-of-a-manifold-at-a-point-given-as-the-kernel-of-the-jacobian-o?rq=1) . Both  OPs are seen more than an year ago and more than a  month ago. So, I am asking the questions in the attempt of OP here: How can I deduce what the OP wrote in third line of his question :"I believe I can say $\phi_*(T_p(V))=T_q(\{q\})=0$." Is that due to the reason that differential of a single point is always zero? I have no question in the answer by : Martin Citoler.

Kindly shed some light on this question of mine in attempt of question of OP.

Comment: If $x\in T_pS$, consider a curve $\gamma$ through $p$ with velocity vector $x$. Since $S=f^{-1}(q)$, we have $f\circ\gamma=$ constant $q$.

Comment: @Berci Do you mind write an elaborate answer. It will really help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532847/the-tangent-space-of-a-manifold-at-a-point-given-as-the-kernel-of-the-jacobian-o?rq=1